# how to remove libpcap-1.6.2

Tags: software-installation, 13.04, libpcap

I have installed libpcap-1.6.2 but when I want to install daq-2.0.4 it requires libpcap-1.0.0 and know I cannot install libpcap because this error occurred:

```
creating hard link `/usr/local/share/man/man3/pcap_datalink_val_to_description.3pcap' to `/usr/local/share/man/man3/pcap_datalink_val_to_name.3pcap': file exists make: *** [install] error 1
```

So I renamed this file "pcap_datalink_val_to_description.3pcap| but the same error caused for other files. What can I do?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me although you can remove libcap-1.6.2 by checking which package provides it by doing **dpkg -S "libcap-1.6.2"** and then removing the package. Is this what you want?

Comment: some file exist in man3 directory because of installing libpcap-1.6 and i don't want this version, when i want to install another version.file of v-1.6  exist and it will not install  . sorry for my pure english

Comment: Ok. AFAIU, you need to remove this one and install an older version of the package. I that case run the command from my previous comment to be sure which package gives "libcap-1.6.2" and then run **apt-cache showpkg <package_name>** to check what other versions are available in the repositories. You can do **sudo apt-get update** before that.

Comment: After being sure which versions are available you an simply remove the package by **sudo apt-get remove <package_name>** or to remove the configuration file too **sudo apt-get purge <package_name>**. After that you may need to remove the links if they still exists and then you can install the desired version by **sudo apt-get install <package_name>=<version>**. If this is what you want then i am gonna put this as the answer.

Comment: this the resulet:E: Unable to locate package libpcap-1.6.2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpcap-1.6.2'
but when i run "sudo make install" in directory of libpcap package, with no error installing got finished

Comment: Got it now, you are compiling the package by yourself. If you are compiling/installing a package by yourself (without apt-get/dpkg) then dpkg/apt-get will not be able to locate the package. You have to delete all its components manually. From the directory of "libcap" package do **sudo make uninstall**, this should work.

Comment: tnx it works well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are compiling/installing a package by yourself (without `apt-get`/`dpkg`) then `apt-get`/`dpkg` won't be able to locate the package. You have to delete all its components manually. From the directory of `libpcap` package do `sudo make uninstall` to uninstall the package.